# Much more verbose /var/log/*

Tags: logs, dmesg

I remember the times when probably literally every log message was being put into `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog`. It was year 2000 if someone's curious. Now it is different. Log files are supposed to be in order but instead  they IMO just lack entries. In my perception 90% of problematic situations are just silent, no way to find anything in `/var/log` files.

How to have `/var/log/messages` back and have it really verbose?

---

**PS.** As an example. When I install vsftpd and do:

```
sudo restart vsftpd
```

then what goes into syslog is following line:

```
kernel: [ 7167.143648] init: vsftpd main process (5823) killed by TERM signal
```

That's the only effect of restarting a FTP server. Think of it – is it possible that vsftpd doesn't output any banner on startup? It's hard to believe to me.

Also, the log comes from *kernel*, it is dmesg that is catching this. That's ridiculous. If kernel would not catch the TERM signal there would be no trace in logs about **restart of *FTP daemon***. This is the case when **proftpd** is restarted via `/etc/init.d/proftpd`. No trace in logs except for `/var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log` which is `proftpd`'s own log file configured by `SystemLog` option.

---

**PS2**: I attach results from Virtual Linux, probably the first live CD created, based on Mandrake, from year 2001 (kernel 2.4.3-20mdk). Restarting proftpd yields there (in `/var/log/messages`):

```
proftpd[2699]: ProFTPD killed (signal 15)
proftpd[2699]: ProFTPD 1.2.2rc1 standalone mode SHUTDOWN
proftpd: proftpd shutdown succeeded
proftpd[2730]: ProFTPD 1.2.2rc1 (release) (built Sun Apr 8 09:53:35 CEST 2001) standalone mode STARTUP
proftpd: proftpd startup succeeded
```

On 14.04 `syslog` is empty and following is logged into `proftpd.log`.

```
proftpd[1326] asus-1201N: ProFTPD killed (signal 15)
proftpd[1326] asus-1201N: ProFTPD 1.3.5rc3 standalone mode SHUTDOWN
proftpd[2620] asus-1201N: ProFTPD 1.3.5rc3 (devel) (built Fri Dec 20 2013 18:04:47 UTC) standalone mode STARTUP
```

On VLinux following is logged into `messages` when `sshd` is restarted:

```
sshd[2821]: Received signal 15; terminating
sshd: sshd shutdown succeeded
sshd[2924]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
sshd[2924]: Generating 768 bit RSA key.
sshd: sshd startup succeeded
sshd[2924]: RSA key generation complete
```

On 14.04 `syslog` is empty, and following is logged into `auth.log` (why there?):

```
Nov 28 09:11:22 asus-1201N sshd[2500]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Nov 28 09:11:22 asus-1201N sshd[2634]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Nov 28 09:11:22 asus-1201N sshd[2634]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

So basically two lines when not counting the third IPv6 line. I then introduced an error into `sshd_config` and repeated the restarts. VLinux / messages:

```
sshd[2924]: Received signal 15; terminating.
sshd: sshd shutdown succeeded
sshd: sshd startup failed
```

On 14.04 this time `auth.log` is empty and `syslog` is not:

```
kernel: [ 2905.854777] init: ssh main process (2718) terminated with status 255
kernel: [ 2905.854836] init: ssh main process ended, respawning
```

On VLinux there is detailed message about error in configuration file printed into console on which I issue `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` ("Bad configuration option: ..."). I wonder if when `sshd` would be started by system then the message would be logged into `messages`. My guess is yes, but I can't test this with live CD.

Restarting proftpd with error in configuration logs full information on VLinux and on 14.04 it outputs error message into terminal when done for the second time, and nothing besides "SHUTDOWN" is logged into `proftpd.log` (`syslog` is empty).

Summary:

- I couldn't prove clearly that `messages` had more information, however it can maybe be seen that what prevails now is to save disk space (?) and not log too much
- one has to jump between `auth.log`, `syslog` and dedicated logs to find some information, and it's mostly meaningless content as apparently no output of the daemons is forwarded into logs and instead it's kernel that catches "something" or daemon's own work to manage own log file
- I'm pretty sure that in case of some sophisticated error I would find something in `messages`, while in current `syslog` there would be typical kernel information about ending an process or so; I might yet came up with an idea of such test to show this
- while I didn't show clearly that current logging misses things, I for sure showed how verbose `messages` was

Comment: `vsftpd` is a bad example, as it keeps its own logs rather than using syslog.  Hence, the messages you're looking for should be in either `/var/log/vsftpd.log` or `/var/log/xferlog`.  Unfortunately there's nothing we can do about that apart from editing the source code for `vsftpd` to use syslog.  For `proftpd`, the level of system logging is given in it's config file.  See [the proftpd manual][http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/configuration_full.html#SYSTEMLOG] for details.  By default, messages from `proftpd` should end up in either `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely one item where the new *systemd* excels - you get all logs in one place.

<sub>I have to admit though that the amount actually logged is not **that** impressive either - the reason as pointed out by Gsxr1k lies in the fact that *vsftpd* logs exclusively to its own files under `/var/log/vsftpd/`</sub>

```
journalctl -f
```

tells systemd to show me the log continuously, so after

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
```

or

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

I get

```
Nov 27 22:45:14 nb-re systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd FTP server...
Nov 27 22:45:14 nb-re systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd FTP server.
Nov 27 22:45:14 nb-re systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd FTP server...
Nov 27 22:45:14 nb-re systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.
```

Answer (score 3):

The config file for what gets logged where is (at least on Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10) `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`.  Looking at that, everything is logged either to `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/syslog`.  I think the second of these is even more verbose than the old `/var/log/messages`.

If you want to get the old `/var/log/messages` back, just uncomment the following lines in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` (and possibly remove `,daemon` from the third line):

```
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
       auth,authpriv.none;\
       cron,daemon.none;\
       mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages
```

Comment: Do you think it's really true level of verbosity? I edited my question, showed that restart of vsftp yields almost no effects in logs (also in messages which I obtained according to your answer).

Comment: `vsftpd` is a bad example, as it keeps its own logs rather than using syslog. Hence, the messages you're looking for should be in either `/var/log/vsftpd.log` or `/var/log/xferlog`. Unfortunately there's nothing we can do about that apart from editing the source code for vsftpd to use syslog.

Comment: I added results from a 2001 distro. Still thinking on an example of problematic situation that would show how easy it was to debug problems back then